# MediaPlayer throws illegalstateexception

Tags: android

**edit3:
Ahaaa! MP crashed when SP "gives sample 14 not READY"...**

edit 2:
I also have a SoundPool in my activity what plays short sound effects and, obviously, it somehow kills the MediaPlayer.
Like the MediaPlayer loads, plays about a second and then dies when SP is loaded.
If I load MediaPlayer at a later time, when SP is already loaded, MP will start playing fine, but will die if I play a few sound FX in SP...

old:
I'm trying to play a music sound file, about 2 minutes long...

```
    try {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(main.this, R.raw.naturesounds );
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

yet it throws

```
06-29 16:50:52.359: E/MediaPlayer(3772): prepareAsync called in state 8
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772): java.lang.IllegalStateException
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at engineDemo.com.main.fillWorld(main.java:132)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at engineDemo.com.main.onCreate(main.java:83)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-29 16:50:52.359: W/System.err(3772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-29 16:50:52.363: W/System.err(3772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-29 16:50:52.363: W/System.err(3772):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas what might be wrong or what's the best way to play background music?

Thanks!

edit:

edited like this

```
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.naturesounds);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            Log.e("ready!","ready!");
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }} );
```

it does show the Log, but still nothing plays...

Comment: after your edit are there any errors in the log cat? or just the "ready!" log?

Comment: just "ready" and it also plays about 1 second of the file. Tried with different files, mp3 and wav, same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example from the [develop docs on MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html):

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        mp.start();

    }
});
//Below this line is the example from docs.
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
//mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

Your MediaPlayer is already Prepared() you don't need to call that after create.

Comment: tried that, but it play only about a second and then stops. :(

Comment: Use the onPreparedListener to make your .start() call. Probably what is happening is it isn't ready yet by the time you call start

Comment: tries, see edit above, it does trigger log, but doesn't play anything.