# How to use MediaPlayer as a static variable?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, static-members

I really need to use MediaPlayer as a static variable, but everytime I try to code for that, it gets different errors. There is no way around it, as I must use 5 different specific instances of MediaPlayer and then call a stop() method on each instance in a different activity from where the instance was first created. This is necessary because I need 5 different mp3 files that need to be used at different times in different activities, but then they must all be stopped in one activity (only one will play at a time, but I want to write code to cover the stopping of all 5, to be efficient).

I have declared my MediaPlayer in activity 1 as a global static variable:  `public static MediaPlayer MP_GODZILLA = new MediaPlayer();`

**Then lower on the page, I get the mp3 file and start it:**

```
public void onFinish() {
                mTextField.setText("ROAR!!");
                // call some media function when timer is done
                MP_GODZILLA.create(GodzillaThemedActivity.this, R.raw.godzilla_roar);
                MP_GODZILLA.start();

                // This disables the pause/play button when timer ends
                Button disablePausePlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
                disablePausePlay.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

**Then, in a separate activity, I need to check if this mp3 is playing, if it is, then I must stop it:**

```
 btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Since this uses the static variable mpGodzilla, must call it from original activity
                if(GodzillaThemedActivity.MP_GODZILLA.isPlaying()){
                    GodzillaThemedActivity.MP_GODZILLA.stop();
                }
            }
        });
```

**But when I run this it does not play any sound, the `MP_GODZILLA.start();` is somehow not working. Instead I get this error:**

```
984-984/com.azurespot.disastertimer.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 1
05-05 07:08:15.185      984-984/com.azurespot.disastertimer.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
05-05 07:08:15.201      984-984/com.azurespot.disastertimer.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
```

**What am I doing wrong? thanks.**

Comment: Better to Create separate `MediaAdapter class` and to create some methods in this class to Handle your `MediaPlayer Object` Statically.

Comment: Thanks @SimplePlan, i will consider how to build this. So you are saying, create a MediaAdapter class, which has all my 5 instances in there, with my 5 static variables, then use those in that single activity to stop them all (if needed)? I saw on the Android Developer pages, there is no MediaAdapter class, so I assume you mean to create my own. Should it extend a particular class in itself?

Comment: yup exactly you make your own `MediaAdapter class` and Maintain only one `Reference MediaPlayer object` on that.

Comment: @Noni A. Your error happens because you didn't call `MediaPlayer:prepare()`/`MediaPlayer:prepareAsync()`, or because you're trying to call `MediaPLayer:start()` before `MediaPlayer:prepareAsync()` has finished its task

Comment: Thanks @Drew, the only thing is before I declared MediaPlayer as static in this class (the Godzilla one), the code worked fine. Although I had a slightly different setup, there was no global variable, the instantiated MediaPlayer was made in the 'onFinish()' method only as it used the .create() method there. My other guess with this error is maybe instantiating it in the global variable, then using .create() is like 2 instantiations which is does not like. But couldn't figure a way around that, as I must get the mp3 resource somehow.

Comment: @Drew... okay, I put `MP_GODZILLA.prepareAsync();` right before the `MP_GODZILLA.start();` in my `onFinish()` method and it gave me a new error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)`.

Comment: Looks like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263173/mediaplayer-throws-illegalstateexception) answer, it says no need to call `prepare()` since `create()` will do this for me.

Comment: @SimplePlan, darn... I am not sure I can create a separate class... the instance is used in 2 places in my Godzilla activity, but setting up those instances in a separate class gives me lots of errors, that were not in the code before... :( Saying "cannot resolve" symbol for many different parts of my code, like the words: create, start, etc... even though I use MediaPlayer class, it is not recognizing it's own methods.